# Android cursor from SQLite crashes on method call

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

Good evening!

I'm trying to read from a SQLite database i just created in my android project. I create the database and enter data without any problems (I think). I query the db to get the data without any runtime complanints and i get a cursor returned from the method call. But the application crashes when i try to use the cursor. "Thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416b72a0).

This is the code i'm trying to run. The toString of the cursor is working fine.

```
 TransactionSQLOH helper = new TransactionSQLOH(context, getDbName(yearS, monthS));
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {"amount", "label", "year", "month", "day", "categoryID", "type", "ID", "time"};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TransactionSQLOH.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    System.out.println(db);
    helper.close();
    System.out.println("Transaction_Check3.1");
    if (cursor == null){
        return null;
    }
    System.out.println("Transaction_Check3.2");
    System.out.println(cursor);
    int test = cursor.getCount();
    System.out.println("Transaction_Check3.3");
    Transaction[] result = new Transaction[10];
```

I get the errror at the line

```
int test = cursor.getCount();
```

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit, log:

```
   02-19 21:08:11.273: I/System.out(21558): Transaction_Check1
   02-19 21:08:11.283: I/System.out(21558): Transaction_Check2
   02-19 21:08:11.283: I/System.out(21558): SQLiteDatabase:                      /data/data/com.SverkerSbrg.Spendo/databases/transactions_201301
   02-19 21:08:11.283: I/System.out(21558): Transaction_Check3
   02-19 21:08:11.288: I/System.out(21558): Transaction_Check3.1
   02-19 21:08:11.288: I/System.out(21558): Transaction_Check3.2
   02-19 21:08:11.288: I/System.out(21558): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@421107d8
   02-19 21:08:11.288: I/System.out(21558): Transaction_Check3.3
   02-19 21:08:11.288: I/System.out(21558): Transaction_Check4
   02-19 21:08:11.288: D/AndroidRuntime(21558): Shutting down VM
   02-19 21:08:11.288: W/dalvikvm(21558): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416b72a0)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3704)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3699)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     ... 11 more
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.throwIfClosedLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:972)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:609)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:349)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:894)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:834)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:196)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:236)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at com.SverkerSbrg.Spendo.Datastructures.Transaction.getMonthTransaciton(Transaction.java:88)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     at com.SverkerSbrg.Spendo.MainActivity.btn2_click(MainActivity.java:43)
   02-19 21:08:11.328: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: post your stacktrace.

Comment: What is TransactionSQLOH ?

Comment: An extended SQLiteOpenHelper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move:

```
helper.close();
```

To after:

```
int test = cursor.getCount();
```

You are getting an `IllegalStateException` exception because you are trying to use a Cursor after the `SQLiteOpenHelper` that accesses the db for it has been closed. This results in an error.